# Clojure: where is my entry point?

Tags: clojure

Typically, Clojure app has `-main` entry point. I'm playing with Compojure:

```
(defroutes app-routes
   (GET "/" [] handle-index)
   ...)

(def app
  (compojure.handler/site app-routes))
```

Where is entry point in this application? Somewhere in Ring, because the command to run is this: `lein ring server-headless`? In any case, what function in entry point in the namespace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your project.clj for an entry `:ring {:handler yourproject.handler/app}`.
For more info, https://github.com/weavejester/lein-ring

Comment: Thanks! I looked for the answer in Compojure and Ring source code, but not in lein-ring.